# Stop formGroup valueChanges observable if ngx typeahead result is clicked

Tags: typescript, observable, angular6, typeahead

I have a FormControl input with a typeahead dropdown, that receives an Observable Subject, after a http call to my API is done.

The issue here is, that my function below, has the valueChanges Observable listening to new inputs. So if a user types "copenhagen", the API returns areas matching the query f.ex.: "Copenhagen, Hovedstaden, Danmark". If that typeahead input is clicked, the valueChanges Observable emits a new value, which makes the typeahead dropdown appear again.

```
subscribeToLocation() {
    const subscription = this.locF.valueChanges
      .pipe(catchError(err => of(err)), debounceTime(800), distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe((formValue: ILocation<any>) => {
        this.initStoryLocationBody(formValue);
      })
  }
```

See images of flow

[image: No input]
[image: First input]

[image: asdasd]
[image: asdasd]

I've already tried to set the emitEvent to false in both `setValue()` and `patchValue()`.

Desired behavoir:
The user types i.e: "copenhagen" - the API fetches locations matching that query - returns array of locations and display in typeahead (this is working) - user clicks a location, and the object.place_name (ex. "København, Hovedstaden, Denmark") shows in the input field, but the typeahead doesn't reappear until the user types in a new query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok im a muffin today...
So i've created an Interface and these variables:

```
interface ILocation<T> {
  location?: string,
  country?: string,
  radius?: number,
  remember: boolean
}

subj = new Subject<ILocation<any>>();
model: any;
```

and my subscription is now depending on the specific subject `.next()`input in  the html:

```
this.subj
  .pipe(catchError(err => of(err)), debounceTime(800), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe((data: ILocation<any>) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.initStoryLocationBody(data);
  })
```

HTML:

```
[(ngModel)]="model" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (input)="this.subj.next({location:model});"
```

I thin it's weird that ngModel shouldnt be used in form inputs connected to a FormGroup, but thats none of my business. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> If that typeahead input is clicked, the valueChanges Observable emits
>   a new value, which makes the typeahead dropdown appear again.

When you take a look into method that `FormControl` has you will see:

```
    setValue(value: any, options?: {
    onlySelf?: boolean;
    emitEvent?: boolean;
    emitModelToViewChange?: boolean;
    emitViewToModelChange?: boolean;
}): void;
```

I guess that you want to change this `emitEvent` to `false`.

Comment: @Buczkowsi: I've already tried that - it still made the valueChanges Observable emit a new value. Tried both `setValue` and `patchValue`. Forgot to mention that, will edit.